# Broadcom BCM43142 WiFi drivers with AP mode to create hotspot for android devices

Tags: drivers, broadcom, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I want to create WiFi hotspot for android device using **Broadcom BCM43142** chipset. 
**OS : 14.0.4**
***but I am stuck at a STEP which says your Wireless card should support AP mode!***
The current  **driver: wl0** which I am using **does not support AP**(access point) mode.

> iw list

Result :

```
Supported interface modes:       
* IBSS       
* managed
```

***I found many drivers for other broadcom chipset like BCM4312 that support AP mode ex : b43 driver but failed to find for BCM43142.***

Is their any driver available for Broadcom BCM43142 that support AP mode?

**OR**
 
Is their any other way I can create hotspot for my android device using 
Broadcom BCM43142 card (os : Ubuntu 14.0.4)? 

Thanks.

Comment: I have found a workaround [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119147/how-do-i-route-traffic-from-wifi-hotspot-to-usb/120280#120280). In the above mentioned link, I used an android hotspot to share internet to other devices. If you need I can make the shared network available to the android device itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no linux drivers for this adapter that support AP mode.

Comment: Damn you 43142 !