# Ubuntu 18.04 Broadcomm BCM43142 Wi-Fi hotspot not working

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, broadcom, hot-spot

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP notebook and installed Wi-Fi drivers successfully but if I try to create a Wi-Fi hotspot, it shows that the hotspot is on but I cannot find the given hotspot on any other device so I guess it was never created. Any help?
Chip ID: BCM43142
PCI ID: 14e4:4365

Comment: is your source internet connection into ubuntu using wired ethernet ?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/635692/broadcom-bcm43142-wifi-drivers-with-ap-mode-to-create-hotspot-for-android-device

Answer (score 1):

There are no Linux drivers that support ap mode .you can't use wifi hotspot